# Python Replace String in File in With clause

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to replace a string in a file.

Below code is simply modifying certain substrings within the bigger string from the file. Any ideas on how I can actually replace line with current_line in the filename?

```
from sys import *
import os
import re 
import datetime
import fileinput

script, filename = argv

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')

username = os.path.split(userhome)[-1]

print "\n"
print "User: " + username

today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print "Date: " + str(today)
print "Current time: " + str(time)

print "Filename: %s\n" % filename

def replace_string():
    found = False
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search("CVS Header", line):
                print line

            ####################################################################################
            #  Below logic:                                                                    #
            #  if length of revision number is 4 characters (e.g. 1.15) then increment by 0.01 #
            #  else if it is 3 characters (e.g. 1.5) then increment by 0.1                     #
            ####################################################################################

                if len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 4:
                    new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0], str(float(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) + 0.01))
                elif len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 3:
                    new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0],     str(float(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) + 0.1))
                ###
                ###
                newer_line = str.replace(new_line, line.split("$Author: ")[1].split()[0], username)
                newest_line = str.replace(newer_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0], today)
                current_line = str.replace(newest_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[1], time)
                print current_line
                found = True
        if not found:
            print "No CVS Header exists in %s" % filename

if __name__ == "__main__":
    replace_string()
```

I tried adding something like..

```
f.write(f.replace(line, current_line))
```

but this just clears all the contents out of the file and leaves it blank so obviously that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) provides a way to edit a file in place. If you use the `inplace` parameter *the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file*.

```
import fileinput

def clause(line):
    return len(line) < 5

for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1):
    if clause(line):
        print '+ ' + line[:-1]
fileinput.close()
```

Trying to apply this idea to your example, it could be something like this:

```
def replace_string():
    found = False
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1): # <-
        if re.search("CVS Header", line):
            #print line

        ####################################################################################
        #  Below logic:                                                                    #
        #  if length of revision number is 4 characters (e.g. 1.15) then increment by 0.01 #
        #  else if it is 3 characters (e.g. 1.5) then increment by 0.1                     #
        ####################################################################################

            if len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 4:
                new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0], str(float(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) + 0.01))
            elif len(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) == 3:
                new_line = str.replace(line, line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0],     str(float(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0]) + 0.1))
            ### 
            ### 
            newer_line = str.replace(new_line, line.split("$Author: ")[1].split()[0], username)
            newest_line = str.replace(newer_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0], today)
            current_line = str.replace(newest_line, line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[1], time)
            print current_line[:-1] # <-
            found = True
        else:
            print line[:-1] # <- keep original line otherwise
    fileinput.close()  # <- 
    if not found:
        print "No CVS Header exists in %s" % filename
```

Comment: I like the logic, but this just prints the new current_line to the file and deletes everything else. Any ideas why?

Comment: If you want to keep the other lines, you have to print them too. See the `else` branch added.

Comment: Well it's not the original line I want to keep, it's all the other content in the file that I am not trying to replace or modify. All of that gets deleted too.

Comment: Actually this works great. I think I understand the logic. When in the if re.search("CVS Header", line) statement, it will print the line that contains that string and then when it hits the else, it will reprint all the lines that don't contain that (i.e. every other line in my file for example). Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. You got the idea :). Then you can modify as you wish the lines that matches your search and leave as it is the rest.

Comment: Just a remark : the Python Standard Library manual says : *if the keyword argument inplace=1 is passed to fileinput.input() or to the FileInput constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file*. So under the hood, this solution does create a backup file ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yep. You are right. If you see my answer I added this remark too. I think it is a useful solution just because of that. Because under the hood it takes care of the backup chore.

Comment: @dreyescat Thanks guys. Also, in my code you'll see that I have something called $Revision. This is a version number (1.1, 1.2, etc.). Problem is, when I hit 1.9 my code will update it to 2.0 (mathematically correct, but not logically). Any ideas on how I can update 1.9 to 1.10? I assume I'd probably have to not use floats..

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by user2040251 is the correct way, and the way used but all text editors I know. The reason is that in case of a major problem when writing the file, you keep the previous version unmodified until the new version is ready.

But of course if you want you can edit in place, if you accept the risk of completely losing the file in case of crash - it can be acceptable for a file under version control since you can always get previous commited version.

The principle is then a read before write, ensuring that you never write something that you have not still read.

At the simplest level, you load everything in memory with `readlines`, replace the line rewind the file the the correct position (or to the beginning) and write it back.

Edit : here is a simple implementation when all lines can be loaded in memory :

```
fd = open(filename, "r+")
lines = fd.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    # test if line if the searched line
    if found :
        lines[i] = replacement_line
        break
fd.seek(0)
fd.writelines()
```

It could be done even for a big file using `readlines(16384)` for example instead of `readlines()` to read by chunks of little more than 16K, and always reading one chunk before writing previous, but it is really much more complicated and anyway you should use a backup file when processing big files.

Comment: Thanks Serge. Please share your implementation when you can.

Comment: @user3495404 : here it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another file and write the output to it. After that, you can just remove the original file and rename the new file.

Comment: That is definitely an option, but I was trying to see if I could just edit the same file and not create another one.